# InteractiveConsole.raw_input override not working

Tags: python

When using code.InteractiveConsole as baseclass with overrides for raw_input and write only the write method is used.

```
>>> input()
''
>>> input("data? ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

The empty input was sourced by the usual console window (sys.stdin instead of the override).

These are the overrides:

```
def raw_input(self, p = ""):
    ''' input function:
            - runs a new thread to simulate input
            sys.stdin is not invoked anymore '''
    sys.stdout = StdOut # break capture, the idle is frozen.
    self.interrupt()
    #print("caught shell input", p)
    self.fire("stdin", self, p)
    self.inline = p
    pos = -1
    while pos < 0:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        pos = self.indata.find("\n")
        if pos < 0:
            l = len(self.indata)
            if l:
                pos = l
    self.inline = ">>> "
    self.fire("inputcleared", self, self.inline)
    data = self.indata[:pos]
    self.indata = self.indata[pos+1:]
    self.updateListing(p+""+data+"\n") 
    sys.stdout = self.out # start capture again, the idle continues.
    return data

def write(self, data):
    ''' stderr simulation:
            fires stderr event '''
    self.updateListing(data) 
    self.fire("stderr", self, data)
```

When adding the method to the locals of the console instance, it works for the console-namespace only. I tested this on Python 3.5 on Windows so far.
Edit: Weirdly I'm getting the mentioned TypeError on Ubuntu-Python3.4+ on the console when using an argument, and the same as on windows without argument. On Ubuntu-Python3.5+ the TypeError does not raise.
Edit again: It seems like my write-override does not work as well on Ubuntu-Python3.4. What is going on there :S

This listing could give **an idea of the solution we found**:

```
>>> class BasicTrigger(object):
    instantValue = "Local value"
    def read(self, length = 0):
        return self.instantValue+"\n"

    def readline(self):
        return self.instantValue

>>> a = BasicTrigger()
>>> a.read()
'Local value\n'
>>> sys.stdin = a
>>> input()
'Local value'
>>> input('Data: ')
Data: 'Local value'
```

The listing was created within an `InteractiveInterpreter` instance, consider not simply just replacing `sys.stdin` with such fun.
The io.StringIO baseclass is not used there. And the 'Data: ' was printed (tracked) out but no newline as it could not trigger the data from BasicTrigger - at this point it's just a redirect.

Anyways, the firing of that TypeError is really strange. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I corrected my code to use `self.compile` instead of `code.compile_command` - but it's not working anyway.

Comment: A lot of the methods you're calling on `self` are not part of the public API for `code.InteractiveConsole`, and it's not clear what they're supposed to be doing. Can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your issue?

Comment: Also, you mention a variety of exceptions in the question. Can you provide tracebacks for them? It's very hard to deduce where an error comes from just from the message and the traceback will point out the exact line causing the exception!

Comment: The traceback would be for `code.InteractiveConsole.runcode` when input is called directly within the idle (so just the one line '<input>'). This is confusing me as well, because what type did i provide to get a "bad argument type for built-in operation"? The code within the override works fine - it's just for event driven operation and listing logging. I'm gonna setup a short test code for you to reproduce it easily.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong by using `code.InteractiveConsole.runcode` because it's a method of it's baseclass. Furthermore this class invokes raw_input wihtin `interact` and i don't really understand how - it looks special: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/code.py

Comment: Or maybe I'm wrong by assumig that it's supposed to replace built-in call's to input, but it would come in handy in a certain way. In that case, adding input to locals and using the other baseclass is the best way out of this. But when trying to run code from a file within such idle, a special method should apply (because of local input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `raw_input` method of the `code.InteractiveConsole` class is only used for the console's own inputs (e.g. the next line of code to run). It doesn't get called for inputs requested by the code that you're running inside the console.

If you want your custom code to supply that too, you need to do more work. Just providing substitue `input` or `raw_input` functions in `locals` will only work for simple situations, where all the input-requestion code is being provided in the interactive session. It won't work if the input is being done in an imported module (which will still have the normal builtins rather than your replacements).

Instead, I'd suggest replacing `sys.stdin` with some other file-like object when you're running code in the session. Here's a quick and dirty implementation that overrides the `runcode` method with a version that swaps out `sys.stdin` while running the code in the console, but not the rest of the time:

```
class CustomInputConsole(code.InteractiveConsole):
    def __init__(self, input_file):
        code.InteractiveConsole.__init__(self) # old style class, so can't use super() here
        self.input_file = input_file

    def raw_input(self, prompt=""):
        self.write(prompt)
        line = self.input_file.readline()
        if line:
            return line.rstrip("\n")
        raise EOFError()

    def runcode(self, _code):
        try:
            old_stdin = sys.stdin
            sys.stdin = self.input_file
            code.InteractiveConsole.runcode(self, _code)
        finally:
            sys.stdin = old_stdin
```

Here's a quick demo, using an instance of `io.BytesIO` as the input file:

```
>>> con = CustomInputConsole(io.BytesIO("""input()
1+2
"""))
>>> con.interact()
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(CustomInputConsole)
>>> 3
>>>
```

Note that the input taken from the file-like object is not echoed, if you want that, you'll need to add it to the logic of the file object.

Comment: But for that logic - wouldn't i except the prompt to show up on sys.stdout?

Comment: Um, yes? The code shown here doesn't try to wrap output, only input. You can do both at the same time, I just wanted to address the one you were specifically asking about in the question.

Comment: Okay, I think 'triggering' the read on stdin is reliable. Thanks